# Get Last Added Product ID of Cart without using checkout session

Tags: magento2, checkout, rest-api, session, quote

I am using RESTful APIs of Magento and I want to get the last added product id of in the cart. All of my searches are using the Checkout Session method of Magento which is

`$this->checkoutSession->getLastAddedProductId();`

But this is not applicable on my end since I am using the RESTful APIs.
Can someone help me if there are any available functionality where I can put a one liner method and class to get this with Quote. 
My other solution is to fetch by 
Quote :: getAllVisibleItems() and get the last item's product id but I believe it would affect the performance.

Thank you for your help folks.

Comment: try below my code in answer's section.

Answer (score 1):

**Try below code**

```
public $cart;

public function __construct(\Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart $cart)
{
    $this->cart = $cart;
}

public function getLastQuoteProduct(){
    $itemsCollection = $this->cart->getQuote()->getItemsCollection();
    $itemsCollection->getSelect()->order('created_at DESC');
    $latestItem      = $itemsCollection->getLastItem(); 
    $product         = $latestItem->getProduct();
    echo 'ID: '.$latestItem->getProductId().'<br />';
    echo 'Name: '.$latestItem->getName().'<br />';
    echo 'Sku: '.$latestItem->getSku().'<br />';
    echo 'Quantity: '.$latestItem->getQty().'<br />';
    echo 'Price: '.$latestItem->getPrice().'<br />';
    echo "<br />";
}
```

**I hope this will work for you...!!!**

Comment: Thanks bro. I will try and see

Comment: @BrandonOrphiano : please let me know if this solution work for you. happy coding :)

Comment: Hi,
From the getItemsCollection i can get the last item, but when i added the same product(111) to cart after adding any other product(222), then i'm getting 222 as last item.
But I want to get the current added product id(111),